# Terminals Of An Electrochemical Cell

Tags: electricity

Does the positivity and negativity of terminals of a battery depend on the terminal where the electrons enter the external circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The positive terminal of a battery is where 'conventional current' comes out of the battery and flows through an external circuit, returning to the battery via the negative terminal. Since electrons are (by convention) negatively charged, the negative terminal of a battery is where electrons are 'released' by the battery.

NOTE: Of course, if it is a secondary battery which is 'recharging', electrons will 'enter' the battery at the terminal marked negative.